# Create an HTML button that works as a link with an "onclick"?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, buttonclick

I'm new in HTML and I would like some help, I would like to create an HTML button that acts like a link.

So, when you click the button, it redirects to a page locally stored in the same file, which is named "page 2 html",

I have a code line:

```
<button type="submit">connect</button>
```

I would like to add a "window.onclick" function to this button which redirect to "page 2 html" and what will be the javascript function that goes with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't. If you want something that acts like a link: Use a link. The browser will give it all the normal behaviours of a link (like being able to right click and copy the URL or open in a new tab or being announced as a link by a screen reader or search engines like Google being able to find the link). If you don't like the way links look: Apply CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do this, If you are stuck to a submit button, you would have to tie it to a form, then make the form's action attribute the link:

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" formaction="https://placekitten.com/">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

or you could do it as a regular button:

```js
var gimmeCats = () => {
  window.location.href = "https://placekitten.com/";
}
```

```html
<button id="catBtn" onclick="gimmeCats()">Click Me!</button>
```

Or, if you aren't opposed to bootstrap, there is this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="https://placekitten.com" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!!!!!!!!!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `window.onclick` will not do it because you are telling your browser that when you click anywhere in the window it will execute it. So you can use `location.replace('')` like this:

```html
   <input type="submit" onclick="location.replace('page2.html')"/>
```

Or using a regular button:

```html
<button onclick="location.replace('page2.html')">Page 2</button>
```

Or by using a `function`:

```html
 <script>
  function redirect() {
   location.replace('page2.html');
 }
 </script>
  <button onclick="redirect()">Redirect</button>
```

You could also just use a normal `<a>` tag:

```html
<a href="page2.html"><button>Redirect</button></a>
```